# не могу понять const

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс

```
class Person{
    char* name;
    friend class Couple;
public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& str,const Person& os);

     explicit Person(const char* n){
        this->name = strdup(n);
        //cout<<this->name<<endl;
     };
     Person(const Person& os);
     Person& operator=(const Person& os);
     ~Person(){
        //cout<<"DEL "<<this->name<<endl;
     }

};
```

и есть класс

```
class Couple{
    Person *wife,*husband;
    public: 
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& str,const Couple& p);

        Couple(const Person& she, Person& he){
            cout<<he.name;;
        };
        Couple(const Couple& other);
        Couple& operator=(const Couple& other);
        //~Couple(); 
};
```

проблема в чём , в мейне они взаимодействуют примерно так

```
int main(void) {
    Person *pjohn = new Person("John"),
            *pjohk = new Person("Jane");
            //delete pjohn;
            //delete pjohk;

            Person mary("Mary") , mark("Mark"); 
            Couple *pcouple1 = new Couple (mary,*pjohn);

}
```

Но я не могу понять могу ли я (если могу) в конструкторе класса Couple как-то присвоить ссылки на экземпляры собственно класса Персонал ?

Comment: Вы пишете на C++, с классами и перегруженными операторами вывода в потоки. Что делают в вашем коде сишные строки и `strdup`?

Comment: @VladD Там по всей видимости нужно решить как вы ответили

Answer (score 3):

Вы передаёте в конструктор ссылки на константные объекты, а ваши указатели — на неконстантные объекты. В этом проблема.

Если вы не собираетесь менять объекты из класса `Couple`, держите внутри указатели на константные объекты. Если собираетесь — передавайте в конструктор ссылки на неконстантные объекты.

Comment: я так понимаю вы имели ввиду так ? 

`class Couple{
 const Person *wife,*husband;
 public: 
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& str,const Couple& p);
  
  Couple(const Person& she, Person& he){
   this->wife=&she;
   cout<<this->wife->name;
  };
  Couple(const Couple& other);
  Couple& operator=(const Couple& other);
  //~Couple(); 
};`

Comment: @user2420249: Именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете передать в конструктор класса `Couple` указатель на экземпляр класса `Person` и присвоить его, например, атрибуту *wife* или *husband*, но учтите, что атрибуты должны также быть константными.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, я думаю, что у вас имеется опечатка в определении данного конструктора

```
Couple(const Person& she, Person& he){
    cout<<he.name;;
};
```

Либо вы имеете в виду

```
Couple(const Person& she, const Person& he){
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    cout<<he.name;;
};
```

либо

```
Couple(Person& she, Person& he){
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
    cout<<he.name;;
};
```

Иначе определение класса выглядит крайне запутанным.

Кроме того, если в определениях параметров конструктора присутствует квалификатор `const`, то соответствующий член класса либо указатель `wife`, либо указатель `husband`, либо оба указателя также должны иметь квалификатор `const`. В противном случае компилятор выдаст диагностическое сообщение.

На мой взгляд У вас есть противоречие в дизайне и использовании классов.

Когда вы создаете объект в динамической области памяти, как в данном случае

```
Couple *pcouple1 = new Couple (mary,*pjohn);
```

то предполагается, что время жизни объекта будет простираться за пределы того блока, где объявлен указатель `pcouple1`, или где существуют инициализаторы `mary` и `*pjohn`, Иначе для этих классов не имеет никакого смысла создавать объекты в динамической области памяти, если время жизни объектов ограничивается тем блоком, где определены соответствующие указатели.

А это чревато неопределенным поведением программы, когда объекты, на которых в классе `Couple` указывают соответствующие члены данных, будут удалены раньше, чем сам объект, содержащий указатели.

Ниже приведена программа, которая демонстрирует это неопределенное поведение.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Person
{
public:
    explicit Person( const char *name ) 
        : name( std::strcpy( new char[std::strlen( name ) + 1], name ) )
    {
    }        
    ~Person() 
    { 
        std::cout << "Person::~Person()" << std::endl; 
        delete [] name;
        name = "Hello undefined behaviour!";
    }
    char *name;
};

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent( const Person &person ) : person( &person ){}
    const Person *person;
};

int main()
{
    Parent *p;

    {
        Person person( "user2420249" );
        p = new Parent( person );
        std::cout << p->person->name << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << p->person->name << std::endl;

    delete p;
}
```

На консоль будет выдано:

```
user2420249
Person::~Person()
Hello undefined behaviour!
```

Как видно из вывода, объект `Person` был уже удален, в то время как объект `Parent` еще живой.

Более того, в качестве аргумента конструктора класса `Parent` вообще может быть задан временный объект, так как константная ссылка может быть связана с временным объектом.

Поэтому в вашем случае лучше в классе `Couple` создавать копии аргументов, а не просто присваивать указателям адреса аргументов, переданных по ссылке.

Такой подход, когда непосредственно указателям присваиваются адреса аргументов, имеет смысл только в том случае, когда время жизни создаваемого объекта не больше времени жизни объектов аргументов, и когда создаваемый объект не является владельцем своих подобъектов.

Comment: а можно пример создания копии ?

Comment: @user2420249 Например, следующим образом:         Couple(const Person& she, const Person& he)  : wife( new Person( she ) ), husband( new Person( he ) ) { 
     
            cout<<he.name;;
        };

Comment: @user2420249 При этом конструктор копирования для класса Person должен быть корректно реализован.

Comment: реализовал но тогда имя не правильно передаётся в данный конструктор

Comment: @user2420249 Значит вы неправильно реализовали.

Comment: Couple принимает вид так `Couple(const Person& she,const Person& he):wife(new Person(she)){cout<<she.name;}`

Comment: а в конструктор копирования у меня имя уже не правильно приходит

Comment: @user2420249 Для класса Person вам надо написать конструктор копирования. Только и всего. Если вы его неправильно пишите, то он и будет неправильным.